# How can I see Adwords Cost and CPC in Google Analytics custom reports?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

Actually I can see under `Acquisition`=> `Acquisition` => `Campaigns` my Adwords Costs and so on. But I do not have these metrics at my custom reports.

Is there a way to get them to there too?

Comment: this page links to some custom reports that you could use which seem to have that data > https://www.dragonsearchmarketing.com/blog/google-analytics-custom-ecommerce-reports/

Comment: Thanks - it is called cost in advertising. But somehow I did not find it when I was creating custom reports.